# Django error after upgrade to 1.6.5

Tags: django, postgresql, django-settings

So previously I was running Django 1.5. After upgrading to Django 1.6.5, I am receiving the following error from the command line:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
```

I am using:

1. **Postgres** as the db backend
2. A clean database, meaning the models have not been synced

I have tried to remove the django.contrib.sites app from the project, but the problem persists. Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Also, I thought it may be a problem with connecting to the database so I switched to a **Sqlite3** backend and received a similar error:

```
File "/Users/tulsa/.virtualenvs/tulsa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 451, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site
```

Comment: are you sure `syncdb` work fine ?

Comment: I receive the same error when I attempt any of the manage.py commands

Comment: i also had same issue. i gone so many steps.. which .. try this one `python manage.py syncdb --traceback --verbosity 2`

Comment: Thanks Raja. Good suggestion. Unfortunately, I tried that as well and received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> A clean database, meaning the models have not been synced

---

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site

solution ==> `./manage.py syncdb`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I receive the same error when I attempt to syncdb or execute any of the manage.py commands (e.g., shell, check, dumpdata).